Exporting an object while declaring vs exporting an object after declaring in Next.js
I was recently writing the middleware.ts file in my Next.js project. And encountered the following situation:
// case 1
export const middleware = (...) => {...} // middleware works

export const config = {
  matcher: '/about',  // matcher works
};

// case 2
const middleware = (...) => {...} // middleware works

const config = {
  matcher: '/about',  // matcher does not work
};

export { middleware, config }

The matcher works in case 1 but does not work in case 2.
I was under the assumption that these ways of exporting functions and objects are equivalent. Is there some difference in practice (in terms of JavaScript modules)? Or is there a difference in the way Next.js is handling these for the middleware.ts file in particular?
Other details: Next.js version 15.0.0-rc.0
EDIT:
I have created this issue on the Next.js Github Repo as well (link). There is a codesandbox for this issue present as well (link).

These two ways of declaring module exports are absolutely equivalent and evaluated the same. They're different syntax for the exact same thing, specifying export like a "modifier" on a variable declaration is just a shorthand. The placement of the export { … } declaration does not matter.

Does this mean the issue lies in how Next.js is getting the exported config object from middleware.ts?

Which issue? If there's a difference, that's a bug in next.js, violating the ECMAScript standard.
